# Getting System.OperationCanceledException while using Azure function with ServiceBusTrigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-function-app, azure-servicebus-topics

I am using Azure function with ServiceBusTrigger. Azure function picks the service Bus Topic message and sends to SingnalR. Getting **System.OperationCanceledException** in AppInsight of azure function. I am using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus package of version 4.2.0 in my azure function code.

Screen shots are attached from AppInsight.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I checked stack trace in AppInsight and it seems this isue is not related to my code. Please suggest who can I solve this issue.

Comment: Is it possible you are using `MessageReceiver`? This [bug](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/6410) might be the cause, which was fixed in v4.1.1 of the Service Bus SDK. Could you share which version of the [extension](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus/) you are using?

Comment: @PramodValavala-MSFT    -  Currently, I am using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus with version 4.1.0. I tried with 4.1.1 version also but issue still exist.